# Updating multiple elements in knockout model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

A lot of times I use the following code in my knockout applications:

```
function VM_someModel(){
    var self = this;

    this.type1 = {
        a1       : ko.observable(false),
        a2       : ko.observable(false),
        a3       : ko.observable(false),
        ...
        b1       : ko.observableArray([]),
        b2       : ko.observableArray([]),
    };


    this.someMethod = function(ID){
        $.post('/url', { ... }, function(o){
            self.type1.a1(o['a1']);
            ...
            self.type1.b1(o['b1']);
        }, 'json');
    }
```

As you see I am assigning all the values from ajax response to my model. I can make sure that result from ajax has the same fields (`a1` ... `b1`) but there can be more fields than 
are available in `type1`.

There is nothing wrong with my code, it works fine, but I just think that all this code inside of my post request could be simplified. I looked into [Loading and Saving data in knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html), but was not able to find anything suited. Another option I have is to iterate through `type1` and extract the same values from `o`, but is there anything knockout specific out there?

P.S. if you know a better title for this post - please edit it.

Comment: Right at the very bottom of the page you linked is this link: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

From the docs:

> This automatically creates observable properties for each of the properties on data. Then, every time you receive new data from the server, you can update all the properties on viewModel in one step by calling the ko.mapping.fromJS function again

So your method would become:

```
this.someMethod = function(ID){
    $.post('/url', { ... }, function(o){
        ko.mapping.fromJS(o, self);
    }, 'json');
}
```